# UICollectionView bigger than NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView embedded in a NavigationController which in turn is embedded in a ContainerView.

The NavigationController views frame width is correctly 964, but the UICollectionView frame width is still 1024.

I cant set any constraints, I thought it would fill to fit the nav controller, not be larger.

What am I missing?

UPDATE: I am using a UICollectionViewController and I am not using any code for this functionality, all done through the storyboard.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: If you are using constraints on collection view you can set the collection view width contraints equal to container view width if the navigation views are also of the same width. else show the code where you setting the collection view frame

Comment: Why can’t you set any constraints?

Comment: All constraints are disabled when I select the collectionview in the storyboard editor.

Comment: Are you using a `UICollectionViewController`, or did you add a `UICollectionView` to a `UIViewController`?

Comment: I am using a UICollectionViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I considered vacawamas question of whether it's a uicollectionviewcontroller or a uicollectionview.  It prompted me to try the uicollectionview which then allowed me to directly apply constraints and it worked!

I still have no idea why the uicollectionviewcontroller didn't work but I'm learning developing iOS apps seems to involve using a lot of workarounds :(